# What is the correct way to await the completion of two Tasks in Swift 5.5 in a function that does not support concurrency?

Tags: swift, async-await, task, swift-concurrency

I have an app that does some processing given a string, this is done in 2 `Task`s. During this time i'm displaying an animation. When these `Task`s complete i need to hide the animation. The below code works, but is not very nice to look at. I believe there is a better way to do this?

```
let firTask = Task {
    /* Slow-running code */
}

let airportTask = Task {
    /* Even more slow-running code */
}

Task {
    _ = await firTask.result
    _ = await airportTask.result
    
    self.isVerifyingRoute = false
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would make the tasks discardable with an extension. Perhaps something like this:

```swift
extension Task {
    @discardableResult
    func finish() async -> Result<Success, Failure>  {
        await self.result
    }
}
```

Then you could change your loading task to:

```swift
Task {
    defer { self.isVerifyingRoute = false }
    await firTask.finish()
    await airportTask.finish()
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Isn't the real problem that this is a misuse of Task? A Task, as you've discovered, is not really of itself a thing you can await. If the goal is to run slow code in the background, use an actor. Then you can cleanly call an actor method with await.

```
let myActor = MyActor()
await myActor.doFirStuff()
await myActor.doAirportStuff()
self.isVerifyingRoute = false
```

However, we also need to make sure we're on the main thread when we talk to `self` — something that your code omits to do. Here's an example:

```
actor MyActor {
    func doFirStuff() async {
        print("starting", #function)
        await Task.sleep(2 * 1_000_000_000)
        print("finished", #function)
    }
    func doAirportStuff() async {
        print("starting", #function)
        await Task.sleep(2 * 1_000_000_000)
        print("finished", #function)
    }
}
func test() {
    let myActor = MyActor()
    Task {
        await myActor.doFirStuff()
        await myActor.doAirportStuff()
        Task { @MainActor in
            self.isVerifyingRoute = false
        }
    }
}
```

Everything happens in the right mode: the time-consuming stuff happens on background threads, and the call to `self` happens on the main thread. A cleaner-looking way to take care of the main thread call, in my opinion, would be to have a `@MainActor` method:

```
func test() {
    let myActor = MyActor()
    Task {
        await myActor.doFirStuff()
        await myActor.doAirportStuff()
        self.finish()
    }
}
@MainActor func finish() {
    self.isVerifyingRoute = false
}
```

I regard that as elegant and clear.

Comment: For an example, see my https://www.biteinteractive.com/swift-5-5-replacing-gcd-with-async-await/ — see the section An Actor Prepares.

Comment: (Another problem with your code is that you seem to be saying `self.isVerifyingRoute = false` on a background thread. That could be a bad idea.)

Comment: Really good linked article! I did notice further down, the old `async { ... }` code blocks, which should probably be updated with `Task { ... }`. Good read, recommend!

Comment: @George You're absolutely right about that change, I need to go back and update the article.

Comment: Nice. Also just as an extra note, I gave this question the `swift-concurrency` tag, because there currently isn't a tag for this for Swift (just using `concurrency` on it's own isn't very specific). Feel free to peer review it & make any changes, so this tag can be used.

Comment: Oooo that new tag is a great idea.